# I can't remove a UIWindowLevelAlert level UIWindow from a notification block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I declare a UIWindow between @interface and @end like this:

```
@interface
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIWindow *aWindow;
@end
```

then I initialized it in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _aWindow = [UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame;
    _aWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    _aWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;
}
```

Now I want to remove this window by calling removeFromSuperview in a NotificationCenter block:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:CloseWindowNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
[self.aWindow removeFromSuperview];
    self.aWindow = nil; 
}
```

It's not working. After calling this, this window is still there.

I tried putting `self.aWindow = nil` outside this block, it works. I also tried use `UIWindowLevelNormal`, and succeed in removing it inside this block.

Can anyone tell me why I can't remove this window inside block?
Thanks!